# PHP - Uploading one or two files (large photos) works fine - uploading 5/6+ doesn't seem to even register (it just shows the upload form)

Tags: php, file-upload, uploading

I have a page with basically this html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="photo_test.php">

<input class="fupload" name="uploadedfile[1]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploadedfile[2]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploadedfile[3]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploadedfile[4]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploadedfile[5]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploadedfile[6]" type="file" />


<input type=submit>
```

and some php to process the files. If a few (typically < 5) photos are uploaded, it works fine

if i upload 5 or 6, it doesn't seem to even register that i've uploaded files. I've tested this with adding  above the code (this is on a stripped down test page to work out whats wrong).

On uploading a couple of photos it works fine (ie in the print_r($_FILES) it shows the file details. on uploading 5 or 6 of them it just prints an empty array (same as uploading nothing)

any ideas?

(this is the full script. uploading one or two images shows data in print_r($_FILES). uploading 5 or more (ish), doesn't show any data. each photo is around 2-3mb)

```
<?


  ini_set('max_upload_filesize', 8388608);
 ini_set('upload_max_filesize', 8388608); 
 ini_set('memory_limit', '125M');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);

?> 


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="photo_test.php">

<input class="fupload" name="uploaded[1]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploaded[2]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploaded[3]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploaded[4]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploaded[5]" type="file" />
<input class="fupload" name="uploaded[6]" type="file" />


<input type=submit>
</form>
```

**the results:**

**if i upload just one file**

```
Array
(
    [uploadedfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [1] => DSCN0426.JPG
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [1] => /tmp/phpNM967F
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 4
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 2824091
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 0
                )

        )

)
Array
(
)
```

**if i upload several files (5 or 6)**

```
Array
(
)

Array
(
)
```

Comment: you dont have to number the name of the uploadfields, you can instead of `uploadedfile[1]` do `uploadedfile[]` - it automatically turns that into a correct array

Answer (score 1):

PHP process the actual upload **before** executing your script (and fill the $_FILES global array with size and tmp path of the file), so any ini_get() or set_time_limit() call in your script would be useless.

You need to fix this in your php.ini, if you are on a shared box you need to ask to your ISP.

Also, remember to increase the 'post_max_size' value too http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: See my edit, it may be what you're trying to explain and sorry I didn't investigate further before saying it would unlikely be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs when upload files's size excess the **post_max_size**.
I meet the same problem when upload 2 large files, when I change this value, it works well.
also, maybe you have to change **upload_max_filesize** value.

if you work on localhost, you can change php.ini easily.
but when you want to change in a server as Cpanel, you can follow this http://www.webhostingzone.org/change-php-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

What's your php.ini's post_max_size?
You have to adjust this value as well (8MB by default), that's why your $_POST array is empty.

EDIT: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size can't be changed using ini_set because their changeable state is set to PHP_INI_PERDIR (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) It should be PHP_INI_USER.

So, you obvisouly stick to the default values (probably 2M and 8M) hence the empty $_FILES.

You have to change these options using the server config (php.ini or apache conf) or a .htaccess file. See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: this doesn't seem to help :/ ive changed them to   ini_set('max_upload_filesize', '125M');
 ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '125M'); 
 ini_set('post_max_size','125M');
 ini_set('memory_limit', '125M');

Comment: @phperroa: I think what paul.ago was trying to say is that you need to set it in the server configuration file, not in the script, because the script is run AFTER the upload exceeds the ini limit. Depsite Capsule claiming he stole his answer, paul might not have the comment ability.

Comment: If you don't have access to php.ini, you can try to add these options using php_value in a .htaccess file. See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: See my edit, your ini_set can't work by design. This limitation might be the result of what paul.ago was explaining.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible the script is timing out. You should try uploading 6 very small files and/or look into `set_time_limit()`

Comment: No, it wouldn't display empty $_FILES and $_POST and would complain about max_execution_time exceeded.

Comment: it isn't timing out, i checked that (like capsule says, it is printing something (the html form also shows, i just didnt include that in the results section)

Comment: Btw, this script is not executing anything (yet). The upload time doesn't count as execution time.